# turn off / disable a script in older browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, fullpage.js

I'm using a script that has problems in older browsers (Internet Explorer up to IE8 and Firefox up to FF3.5). Is there a way to disable it if the site is loaded with these browsers? Please be clear and simple because I don't know JavaScript, thanks in advance!

P.S. the script I want to disable in old browsers is fullpage.js

Comment: Firefox 3.5? That is ancient. No one uses that. For IE you could use `<!--[if lte IE 7]>`

Comment: You are going to have to use conditional statements within fullpage.js itself. A combination of `navigator.appVersion` and `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1` is a good start to detecting the firefox version. As for detecting IE, html conditional statements won't be a good solution because you can't exclude a script inclusion that you need for other browsers as other browsers will not parse the conditional statement. However you could use `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>var oldIe = true;</script><![endif]-->` and detect if oldIe exists within fullpage.js

Comment: Could you be more clear?
I have to insert a conditional comment:
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script>
</script>
<![endif]-->
but what I have to write in the script tag?

Comment: I would only care for IE. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I understand how to use the conditional comment, but what I have to insert inside? There is a specific rule to disable another script?

Comment: You insert inside everything you want to hide from old IE versions

Answer (score 0):

as said, you unlikely to have to worry about anything other than browsers less than IE8.

EDIT: changing this to include other browsers.  I was being a bit thick!!

Firstly, download the Modernizr plugin from [here](http://modernizr.com/download/) and call it into your page.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/pathTo/modernizr.js"></script>`

then call in the fullpage.js file as you were

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>`

then inside a document.ready, detect if CSS3 is supported and either call the fullpage method or not.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if($(html).hasClass('csstransitions'))
    {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
    }
});
```

this will mean it feature will only be turned on if the browsers supports CSS3 (by detecting transitions), thus leaving out IE8 and below and including all others.

Comment: Thank you for your help! writing this does fullpage.js will not load in IE7 and earlier? (this is what I want to do)

Comment: It should be `gte` (greater or equal), not `lte` (less or equal) than `IE8` instead of `IE7`, because `fullPage.js is fully functional on all modern browsers, as well as some old ones such as Internet Explorer 8, 9, ...`

Comment: so I have to write:
<!-- [if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->

Is it right?
But does it will load in other browsers too? (Webkit, Moz, O)

Comment: oops my mistake, ive changed that in the example

Comment: Hey guys so if i call fullpaje.js only in this conditional comment it will work too in other browsers (Chrome, FF, O..) or not?

Comment: changed my answer, I misunderstood your needs sorry.  Its a little more work but still simple code.

Comment: This is not a good solution for the problem. CSS3 is not supported in IE 8 and 9 but the plugin fullpage.js works perfectly well on both of them by using jQuery animations. CSS3 detection is not the way to go to detect whether or not fullpage.js will work.

Comment: IE 9 does support css3. The Op wanted a way to isolate IE8 and below which is what the script does.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can make sure that the code checks the functions that are causing the errors are available before running the script.

```
if (typeof yourFunctionName == 'function' && typeof yourFunctionName2 == 'function') {
    //Your code here
}
```

Use && to only run the code if all functions exist.

This will insure that your code is only run on browsers that are compatible and avoids any guessing.

Can I Use is also helpful for tracking down available functionality, for various versions of browsers
http://caniuse.com/#cats=JS API